# WordPress: Can't access wp-admin and got plain white page

Tags: wordpress

I develop a website with CMS WordPress. I don't have any errors on my localhost. I uploaded it on web server and it's fine. But, I can't go wp-admin and I got a plain white page. I enabled error reporting and got just two warning. I solved it and reloaded. Unfortunately, I still got a plane page. Is there any way to solve this problem? Please favor me and thanks for your time.

Comment: What does it say in your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force deactivate your plugins:
http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get your answer and that link while I was fixing my problem. Thanks anyway.